# Can a twist tie be used as a jumper for HVAC?

Tags: hvac

I just moved into a new house and I'm putting in a new thermostat.

The old one had a little jumper wire between RC and RH, but my new thermostat has these two terminals spaced a few inches apart.

It's warm here and I don't have a way to get to the hardware store quickly...

Is it risky or dangerous to use a twist tie (like what you have on a bag of bread) as a jumper? Note that it can be stripped so only the leads are exposed metal and the plastic is still in the middle of the wire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a pinch, well you have to do what you have to do.  It's a wire, albeit a steel one, so it's not going to do as well conductivity-wise as a copper wire, but as long as it doesn't short out to any of the other terminals you should be OK.

The wiring in a thermostat is 24V not 120/240V like other electrical systems in you home, so the danger is significantly reduced.  But don't let it sit that way for an extended period of time.  The "insulation" was meant for one purpose which was not to insulate a conductive wire for a long period of time.

Did you check around for another wire that you could scavenge? An old speaker wire or something from your garage.  Just thinking out loud...

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but this sounds like it could easily evolve into a "yeah, I guess I should have gotten around to it before it caught fire" kinda situation...

Comment: if the wire isn't even warm when used, it won't catch fire. Jumper wires, being designed for signal-level current, are often 30awg, not a lot or any less than a twist-tie. The run is short and it's open-air cooled, so I doubt resistance will amount to anything worth considering.